# How do I properly use formik reset form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have formik form that needs to clear after clicking a button on the form. I am trying to use the resetForm function but it isn't working. This is being used to add to a list of items displayed in a table. I have provided a snippet of my code below. What am I missing? Could the issue be related to me using the MUI 5 button instead of the regular html one?

Initial Values Object

```
const orderFormInitialValues = {
    itemId: undefined,
    quantity: undefined,
    unitPrice: undefined,
};
```

The form

```
<Formik
    initialValues={orderFormInitialValues}
    onSubmit={() => { }}
    validationSchema={
        yup.object().shape({
            itemId: yup.number()
                .required('You must select an item.'),
        })
    }>
    {({
        values,
        errors,
        handleChange,
        validateForm,
        setFieldValue,
        resetForm,
    }) => (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={7}>
                    <Typedown
                        label="Item"
                        id="itemId"
                        options={orderState.items.filter((b) => orderState.order.orderItems.map((i) => i.itemId).includes(b.itemId) === false).map<TypedownOption>((item) => ({ value: item.itemId, name: item.name} as TypedownOption))}
                        value={values.itemId}
                        updateSelection={(selected?: number | string) => {
                            if (selected !== undefined) {
                                setFieldValue('itemId', selected);
                            }
                        }}
                        error={!!(errors.itemId)}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <InputTextField
                        label="Quantity"
                        keyName="quantity"
                        type="number"
                        value={values.quantity}
                        error={!!(errors.quantity)}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <InputTextField
                        label="Unit Price"
                        keyName="unitPrice"
                        type="number"
                        value={values.unitPrice}
                        error={!!(errors.unitPrice)}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={1}>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        sx={{
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                        }}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            addOrderItem(values, validateForm).then(() => {
                            });
                            resetForm({ values: orderFormInitialValues });
                        }}>
                        Add
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Add Order Item

```
const addOrderItem = (orderItem: any, validateForm: any) => new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    validateForm()
        .then((formKeys: any) => {
            if (Object.keys(formKeys).length === 0) {
                const item = orderState.items.find((b) => b.itemId === orderItem.itemId);
                if (item) {
                    setOrderState({
                        ...orderState,
                        order: {
                            ...orderState.order,
                            orderItems: [...orderState.order.orderItems, {
                                itemId: item.itemId,
                                name: item.name,
                                quantity: orderItem.quantity,
                                unitPrice: orderItem.unitPrice,
                                total: orderItem.quantity * orderItem.unitPrice,
                            }],
                        },
                    });
                    resolve();
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Edit: Added Add Order method.

Answer (score 2):

Just use resetForm(). Without passing any value.

Change resetForm({ values: orderFormInitialValues }) to resetForm()

resetForm requires values only when you want to set a nextState. If no value is provided then it resets to the original state, which is what you want.

I don't know why resetForm with the provided values does not work. Check what mutations you are making and what that state is before setting it. Might help detect your issue.

Also you can try handling the reset in your onSubmit function like this:

```
    <Formik
        initialValues={orderFormInitialValues}
        onSubmit={(values, {resetForm}) => {
          console.log('The values', values)
          resetForm()
        }}
        validationSchema={
            yup.object().shape({
                itemId: yup.number()
                    .required('You must select an item.'),
            })
        }>
        {({
            values,
            errors,
            handleChange,
            validateForm,
            setFieldValue,
            resetForm,
            handleSubmit
        }) => (
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={7}>
                        <Typedown
                            label="Item"
                            id="itemId"
                            options={orderState.items.filter((b) => orderState.order.orderItems.map((i) => i.itemId).includes(b.itemId) === false).map<TypedownOption>((item) => ({ value: item.itemId, name: item.name} as TypedownOption))}
                            value={values.itemId}
                            updateSelection={(selected?: number | string) => {
                                if (selected !== undefined) {
                                    setFieldValue('itemId', selected);
                                }
                            }}
                            error={!!(errors.itemId)}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <InputTextField
                            label="Quantity"
                            keyName="quantity"
                            type="number"
                            value={values.quantity}
                            error={!!(errors.quantity)}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <InputTextField
                            label="Unit Price"
                            keyName="unitPrice"
                            type="number"
                            value={values.unitPrice}
                            error={!!(errors.unitPrice)}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={1}>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            sx={{
                                height: '100%',
                                width: '100%',
                            }}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                addOrderItem(values, validateForm).then(() => {}).catch(e => console.log(e));
                                handleSubmit()
                            }}>
                            Add
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )}
    </Formik>
```

Comment: Still not clearing

Comment: I added modifications to your code. That might help you debug it or even fix it. 
1. An error might happen in the addOrderItem promise. You don't have a catch on that promise.
2. validateForm is a promise too. Check what promise fulfills and the order.
3. You are not using a form.

Comment: Not sure the addOrderItem method is the issue as it currently works, I added its code for context.

Comment: Sir. If your functions work. When you copy my code and Click the button you should get to the onSubmit and console.log the values. If you cannot see any values in your console after copying the code and trying to click  the button. The error happens in the addOrderItem function. If not. There's something else.